# Can't distribute users into equal groups using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop

This is the first question I have put on stack overflow. I'm a bit of a newbie.

I am trying to automatically assign students to random and equal(or mostly equal if assigned an odd number) groups. Right now, I am just trying to generate the group assignments. Later this information will be stored in a DB (not there yet) and the teacher will be able to modify the number of groups.

I can get the students assigned to different random groups but it won't divide them equally. I feel like the problem is in:

```
while ($rand_num == $value && $group_count[$rand_num] >= $group_size)
```

It doesn't seem like it is making the comparison or is ignoring everything after the &&.

```
<?php
$group_array = array("Abby" => 0 , "Billy" => 0 , "Cathy" => 0 , "Dillan" => 0, "Elizabeth" => 0 , "Fred" => 0 , "Geofery" => 0 , "Hank" => 0, "Ingrid" => 0 , "Jacob" => 0 , "Kylie" => 0 , "Lenord" => 0);

$class_size = count($group_array);
$num_groups = 3;
$group_size = $class_size / $num_groups;
$group_count = (array_count_values($group_array));

foreach ($group_array as $key => &$value) {
    $rand_num = rand(1 , $num_groups);      
    while ($rand_num == $value && $group_count[$rand_num] >= $group_size) {
        $rand_num = rand(1 , $num_groups);
    };
    $value = $rand_num;
    $group_count = (array_count_values($group_array));
};
//Group Assignments
var_dump($group_array);
//Users in each group
var_dump($group_count);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so you like to divide them equally and randomly in the same time, right?

Comment: You can use shuffle for the array of users and then select the first to put into group one, then shuffle the array again and put the first one in group two, continue untill the array is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you a simpler and cleaner approach.

Example for 4 groups:

1. Shuffle the students in random order
2. Assign group 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3 etc.

You could implement it like this:

```
<?php
$n_groups = 4;
$students = array("Abby", "Billy", "Cathy", "Dillan", "Elizabeth", "Fred",
    "Geofery", "Hank", "Ingrid", "Jacob", "Kylie", "Lenord");

shuffle($students);  // put students in random order
$groups = []; // init empty groups
foreach($students as $position => $student) {
    $groups[$student] = $position % $n_groups;  // put student into group based on his position (first student gets 0, then 1, 2, 3, then 0 again etc.)
}
print_r($groups);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does your `$group_array` have the name of the students as keys? Any purpouse on that?

I have come up with this:

```
$students_array = ['Abby', 'Billy', 'Cathy', 'Dillan', 'Elizabeth', 'Fred', 'Geofery', 'Hank', 'Ingrid', 'Jacob', 'Kylie', 'Lenord', 'Katy'];
shuffle($students_array);

$class_groups = 3;
$groups = [];

foreach ($students_array as $key => $student) {
    
    $assigned_group = $key % $class_groups;
    $groups[$assigned_group][] = $student;      
}

print_r($groups);
```

I have made more readable the vars. And put the students groups into one array.

In the case you get an odd number of students you will end up with one group having +1 student.

I think your problem was trying to assign the students randomly into groups, assigning them sequentially into the groups will ensure the groups have an equal number of students.

As for the `$key % $class_groups` value, it's using the 'modulus' php's arithmetic operator.

> The "mod" operator in computer languages is simply the remainder. For
> example,

> 17 mod 3 = 2

> because

> 17 / 3 = 5 rem 2

> which in turn means

> 17 = 3 * 5 + 2

> There are some tricky issues when negative numbers are used, but that
> shouldn't ordinarily be necessary.

> In math (number theory), the term is used a little differently. The
> "modulus" is actually not the remainder, but the number you are
> dividing by; and "mod" is not an operator, but a label telling "in
> what sense two quantities are considered congruent, or equal." For
> example, we would say

> 17 = 11 (mod 3)

> (read as "17 is congruent to 11, modulo 3"), meaning that 17 and 11
> both leave the SAME remainder when divided by 3. You probably won't
> see this usage if you are only reading about programming, but it's
> worth being aware of if you look deeper into the math behind it.

You can read that from [here.](https://web.archive.org/web/20171220131652/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54363.html)